# How to apply a cut function on an index

Tags: python, indexing, pivot, pivot-table, cut

I would like to split a `dataframe` in 2 distinct parts.
The first one will be the mean of the 9 first rows and the second part will be the remaining raw.

I would like to see an average of the first 9 lines to compare it with the last line.

Basically, I spitted the `dataframe` with a `cut` function and then I tried to apply a `pivot_table`, which is working.

Then I applied the `pivot_table` function which is not working.  As per my understanding, the day is the index and not the column name, which leads to an issue in the `pivot_table` function.

[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to split list `l` into two parts, one part only has the last element of the list, and the other part has all but the last element of the list. Yo can do that by simply calling `l2 = l.pop()`. Now `l2` will have the last element, and `l` will have the rest.

---

This function will return the mean of the list *(excluding the last element of the list)* passed into the brackets, and the last element of the list:

```
l = [3,4,5,2,9,6,7,4,5,6,7,3,4,5]

def compare(l):
    return l.pop(), sum(l)/len(l)

print(compare(l))
```

Output:

```
5, 5.0
```